# How to detect Nokia X

Tags: android, nokiax

I'm trying to deploy my android app to the new **Nokia X** android phone but it doesn't appear to devices list.

On website they say:

*The USB drivers are available via the SDK Manager under extras in **Nokia X USB Driver package**. When installed, the drivers can be found in \extras\nokia\usb_driver folder.*

http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/getting-started/device-setup.html

I don't find it in the SDK manager. I also tried with google usb driver.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UPDATE:

From their own site:

**The steps for installing the Nokia X packages with the SDK Manager are the following:**

Open the SDK Manager and select Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites...
Open User Defined Sites tab and click the New... button
Enter the following URL to the Add Add-on Site URL dialog:
http://tools.nokia.com/nokia-x/repository/addon.xml
Copy code
Click OK
Click the Close button to close the Add-on Sites window

Then you need will be able to see their addon package, install it in SDK manager and see Nokia USB driver in /extras/

**WINDOWS**

Edit the file C:\Users\.android\adb_usb.ini and add line:

```
0x0421
```

then restart adb server.

**Enabling USB debugging**

In order for the ADB tool to recognise your device, you need to enable the USB debugging on the device by following these simple steps:

Launch device settings.
Tap Developer options in the System section.
Switch on developer options and tap OK in the query dialog shown.
Enable USB debugging in the Debugging section and tap OK in the query dialog shown.
Your device has now USB debugging enabled.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Seems you have forgotten to add Nokia addon to SDK Manager.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Do you know any way to install the Google play services on this phone?

Comment: I think it's not possible until custom roms are out. It's too heavily dependent on core android services, I suspect Nokia got rid of them.

Comment: http://m.androidcentral.com/nokia-x-rooted-and-google-apps-installed-android-android

Comment: Nokia X usb driver not compatible with ubuntu.

Comment: The URL for the SDK addon's is now invalid

Comment: @JaredKells Check my answer. I have provided link to a website which has driver installer.

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS X the procedure is as follows, see [device setup guide for Linux and Windows](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/getting-started/device-setup.html):

1) Download and install [Nokia X SDK](http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/downloads)

2) Update adb_usb.ini with Nokia X USB Vendor line in Terminal:

```
sudo nano ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

0x0421
```

3) Update and restart adb server in Terminal

```
sudo android update adb
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

4) On Nokia X phone go to Settings > Developer Options > Allow USB debugging

5) Check for Nokia X device in Terminal

```
adb devices
```

Comment: Both links are no longer valid, they redirect to a page stating that *"As of March 31, 2015, Developer.nokia.com has been deactivated as a result of the Microsoft acquisition of the Nokia Devices and Services business. Relevant content is now available from Microsoft or via Opera."*

Comment: @Ifurini Check my answer. I have provided link to a website which has driver installer.

Answer (score 0):

Download *ADB Driver Installer* from [adbdriver.com](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) and unzip the package. Make sure you have enabled the developer options and USB debugging in your mobile, and connect to computer. Then, run *ADBDriverInstaller.exe* from the extracted folder. Select the device and click on *Install*. It worked perfectly for me. My device was then recognized in Android Studio.